# Networking stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

After I've restarted my Ubuntu 16.04 (on Lenovo Thinkpad T530), networking stopped working. It worked perfectly before...
The "enable/disable networking" menu does not even show, and running nm-applet does nothing.

If I restart the network-manager, a message is displayed: "Disconnected - you are now offline".

rfkill shows that "Wireless LAN" is soft blocked but it does not matter if I unblock it.

Do you have any idea what should I check/run to enable networking?

(I know my problem is very specific and not well-defined but if you have any suggestion I can provide any further info...)

Comment: I tried a "Live CD" Ubuntu version to prove that there is not hardware problem - it worked perfectly as expected...

Comment: It seems that the network interfaces have been renamed after the update. E.g. eth0 was renamed to enp0s25...