# Suddenly Ubuntu 16.04 is not able to recognize any drivers: sound, wifi, video, usb?

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, sound, updates

Till last night it was working perfectly, I did however had a request for restart for an update I had installed.

This is from a different computer (:)).

Can someone help? I dont know what else to write.
Tried ifconfig, lspci -v, aplay -l commands. All show no drivers detected.
How come all of a sudden?

Please help

Comment: I have similar problem but no solution yet: http://askubuntu.com/questions/837102/networking-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: It's not just network, it's everything in my case. Will resort to Windows 10, if I don't get a solution today

Comment: Boot to the previous kernel,  there 2 ways to do that : see  http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version